# How to change the key for autocompletion in ZSH?

Tags: zsh, keyboard-shortcuts, autocomplete

I'm on Ubuntu Mate 16.04 using terminator as my terminal. And using `zsh` version 5.1.1. I'd rather change the keybinding to the left arrow key to emulate fish in a way. Anyone know how?

Answer (score 4):

You can bind completion to left arrow with

```
bindkey '^[[D' expand-or-complete
```

where `^[[D` represents left arrow (run <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> or `cat` and hit arrow key to test that).

If you also want to unbind <kbd>Tab</kbd> key then

```
bindkey -r '^I'
```